# How do I pass values to a Perl program as command line arguments from C#?

Tags: c#, perl

I have a problem with some Perl code. I used C# to pass some parameters to perl and call one Perl script to execute the code. But the parameters don't go through.

Is it the right way to give value to parameters in Perl like this?

```
  my ($x, $y, $z) = @ARGV;
```

Also, this is the code in C# that passes the values.

```
  string fullPath = @"C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe";
  string arguments = @"C:\Users\Desktop\old.pl"
                    + " " + dir_f + " " + file_f + " " + factor_f;
                Process myProcess = Process.Start(fullPath, arguments);
                myProcess.WaitForExit(999);
                if (!myProcess.HasExited)
                {
                    myProcess.Kill();
                    throw new Exception("Timed out while running process");
                }
```

Comment: Why are you passing "999" to the wait for exit? That parameter is milliseconds, so if it takes more than .999 second to start up the perl script, its going to time out.

Comment: That is how you read command line parameters in Perl.  Did you verify dir_f, file_f and factor_f have content?  Also, I'd have your program exit right after $x, $y and $z are assigned and have them print to standard output right then and there.  If I had to guess, this is a scope issue, but without seeing more code, it's difficult to guess.

Comment: @Hambone, thanks for the reply. I checked dir_f, file_f and factor_f have content, they are string variables. My goal is to pass these three params to perl, name them and print them elsewhere.

Comment: @RonBeyer, thanks for the reply. I just changed the wait time but there is no change of the result.

Comment: the perl code works fine when I define variables like this: $dir_f = "hello";   @file_f={"world"}; $factor_f =10. so I am wondering if something wrong with the pass-value

Comment: Have you verified that the perl script actually executed?  I don't know C# so I could be off base here but does it use \ as its escape character like perl and some other languages?

Comment: I can't help but notice your path is `c:\users\Desktop.`  While not impossible, this is curious.  Normally, it's `c:\users\UserName\Desktop`.  To me it almost looks like you're running Perl.exe with no actual filename (which would cause Perl to puke and return immediately)